# how to register a new option with coap.registerOption

Tags: javascript, node.js, coap

I'm using node-coap in order to send data to a coap server, I need to use a custom option in the packet so I'm running this code:

```
var req = {
 hostname:"localhost",
 method:"PUT",
 pathname:"create1",
}
    var coapReq = coap.request(req)
    coap.registerOption('newOption',toBinary,toString)
    coapReq.setOption('newOption',b.from('Hello World'))
    coapReq.end()
```

The function toBinary and toString are defined as follow:

```
function toBinary(data){
    return b.from(data)
}

function toString(data){
    return data.toString()
}
```

This piece of code is not working. What is the correct way to use the registerOption method?

Comment: Have you fixed it yet? Please append the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the node-coap readme, an example of setOption uses a numeric name for the custom option.

```
var coap = require('coap')

function toBinary(text){
  return new Buffer(text);
}

function toString(data){
  return data.toString()
}

coap.registerOption("555", toBinary, toString)

server = coap.createServer()

server.on('request', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.options);
  res.end()
})

// the default CoAP port is 5683
server.listen(function() {
  var req = {
    hostname:"localhost",
    method:"PUT",
    pathname:"create1",
  }
  var coapReq = coap.request(req)
  coapReq.setOption('555', "Hello World")

  coapReq.on('response', function(res) {
    res.pipe(process.stdout)
    res.on('end', function() {
      process.exit(0)
    })
  })

  coapReq.end()
})
```

And the options were:

```
[ { name: 'Uri-Path', value: <Buffer 63 72 65 61 74 65 31> },
{ name: '555', value: 'Hello World' } ]
```

It is not possible to pass a alphabetic option name as node-coap uses coap-packet module where option name is parsed like integer:

https://github.com/mcollina/coap-packet/blob/master/index.js#L342

I'd recommend you to create an issue/PR at node-coap github repo to make more clear explanation of this at README.